# Django error when trying to access database in network directory

Tags: django

Now this may be something very foolish to do, but please allow me to discuss my issue.  I am attempting to have Django access a database on a remote device by accessing it's network directory like so (in the settings.py script):

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
    'NAME': '/run/user/1004/gvfs/sftp\:host\=169.254.131.151\,user\=root/root/injection_log2.sqlite',
}}
```

I've successfully created a file, viewed a file, and edited a file through Vim and that exact directory.  So doing this should work right?  But I am getting the following bug:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 399, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 89, in handle
    executor = MigrationExecutor(connection, self.migration_progress_callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 20, in __init__
    self.loader = MigrationLoader(self.connection)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.build_graph()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 176, in build_graph
    self.applied_migrations = recorder.applied_migrations()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 65, in applied_migrations
    self.ensure_schema()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 52, in ensure_schema
    if self.Migration._meta.db_table in self.connection.introspection.table_names(self.connection.cursor()):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 207, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

So in conclusion I have a few questions!  Is what I am doing possible?  If so, what am I doing wrong?  If not, is there some good alternative?  Thanks!  Also I'm working on Ubuntu if that helps!

Comment: No, that is not possible. If you want your database on a remote server, use a real server-based database like Postgres or MySQL.

Comment: Can you suggest a tutorial that I can follow to figure that out?